# Modifying Wordpress search function to coordinate with Yoast SEO

Tags: search, wordpress

I am attempting to incorporate search functionality for a WordPress website that contains a multitude of posts.  Each post title is a random number, but I have manually inputted the titles into the SEO Title field using the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin.  The posts themselves have no other identifying material (e.g., tags or content).  When integrating the search bar, I noticed that I was not receiving any results as the search is utilizing the original random number title and not the SEO Title.  I’ve explored a few of the custom search plugins, but none of them permitted me to add the SEO Title field within the search criteria.  Any suggestions on how I can alter the search function to focus on the SEO Titles and not the original title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi).

The Yoast SEO title is stored as a custom field on the post. You should be able to configure [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi) to search that field. The nice thing here is that this will modify WP's built-in search so you won't have to make any changes to the theme.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I tried using Relevanssi at first, but didn't see the option to include the post custom fields.

Comment: Look under **Custom fields to index** then add "_yoast_wpseo_title" (the custom field key of the Yoast SEO title) then re-build the index.